# SQL Server : query run-time slowed down after reinstalling database

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-ec2

I use Microsoft SQL Server 2014 that I have installed on an Amazon EC2 instance on which I have attached a volume where the SQL Server database is stored.

**Cause**: I had to reinstall the entire Database this week due to some malware issues.

**Problem**: after the re installation, the query run-time has significantly increased. Something that took 1 minute takes now 17 minutes.

The problem here is not the connection with the EC2 instance as that has stayed the same. I suspect therefore that the problem lies in how the SQL Server database is set up.

I tried running the query by including the actual execution plan and then inspecting if there are some indexes missing. However, I could not find any missing indexes.

So given that my queries have stayed the same, I do not miss any indexes, what could be the reason that it has slowed down so much? And what can I do about it?

Comment: `And what can I do about it?` show DDL, your query, actual execution plan?

Comment: Its quite big, cannot take a picture of the whole of it. How do you suggest I share the actual execution plan. In any case, I understand that the query can be optimized, but I am more wondering in this question why the same query is now taking longer when a Database has been reinstalled. Is there something I forgot to turn on for instance?

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: The first time a query run index has to be build and statistic created. But after that should run as expected. My suggestion split your complex query into small pieces and start test/check the query plan.

Comment: @IvanStarostin XML too big to past it there :(

Comment: Why are you surprised that it does not complete in 0.0001s? Show your DDL and query.